# C# From what Form another form is opened?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Let's say I have 10 Forms .  each one contain 1 `Button` . Each `Button` open a Form named `Else` my `Else` form contain a `Textbox` . but I want from this text of `Textbox` to change depends from what form I opened "Else" Form . How Can I possibly do that ? thank you

Comment: you can pass argument "this" to the constructor of the form. is it a problem?

Comment: Care to change your form names?

Comment: I care about the textbox Content .
If I opened "Else" using "Form1" , textbox text = "Hello"
if I opened "Else" using "Form2" , textbox text = "Hey" for example ..

Comment: @Stackoverflow Where does this choice need to be made? What if you create a new form as your source?

Comment: Try passing this.Name to "Else" form's constructor by overloading its constructor  i.e. current form's name to "Else" form and check accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the text you want to be displayed into `Elses`'s constructor. Simples.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing this.Name to "Else" form's constructor by overloading its constructor i.e. current form's name to "Else" form and check accordingly.